# CoreData NSDate SQLite precision discrepancy

Tags: sqlite, core-data, nsdate, precision

I've seen a few questions which float around this topic but nothing which quite matches.

I'm creating a Timestamp as part of a primary key. The timestamp is set with [NSDate date] and is stored in a SQLite store. When I look into the store the dates have full precision (up to 7 decimal places indicating 100 nanosecond precision).

I have services running on a server which I need to send the data to and retrieve the date from. The sending process serializes the data and in order to send the date with the required precision (stored as datetime2 in SQL Server) I use:

```
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
   [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS'Z'"];
   NSString *stringFromDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:dateTime];
```

and vice versa when retrieving the date from the server.

The problem is that the date being retrieved from the store is for some reason ONLY at millisecond precision. So if I have a Timestamp in the store as 341196557.808558, retrieve into an NSDate and then use the above code to generate a string is reads as "2011-10-24'T'08:48:17.8090000".

This gets sent to the server which dutifully stores it as millisecond precision (because that's all it's getting). When I then retrieve the date, deserialize it and try and use a predicate fetch against the store it doesn't return the record because the dates aren't equal. Doing a < or > comparison won't work because it's a primary key... I need ==

I wouldn't mind dropping to millisecond precision on the timestamp prior to saving (if I could work out how) but it seems extremely odd to me that the original date can store and save microsecond precision but doesn't keep the same precision when retrieving the date from the store?

Would love any thoughts on this, or that gem one-liner which sorts this mess out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I do not know why the nanosecond precision is being dropped (that surprises me and you should file a radar on it) what I can say is that:

Timestamps are a terrible primary key.  If you can change that I would highly recommend it.

If you must use Timestamps then I suggest storing the `-timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` in Core Data instead and then reconstruct the date whenever you need to send it to the server.

### Update

Timestamps are a pain (as you are experiencing) and wasteful from a purely DB point of view since you never use all of them in order.

Depending on what you are trying to do a INT64 incremented (not easy with Core Data) works well.  If you are using the timestamp for more than just part of the unique key then I would just keep it as a NSTimeInterval (double) as I suggested above.  That will keep your precision and avoid messing with strings.  Keep in mind that strings can be quite slow.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have a feeling it's related to the NSDateFormatter and am now deliberately pushing dates through to string and back again prior to storage as a means of 'normalising' them so that they will survive the round-trip to the server. (still hoping someone will point me to some code on just limiting the NSDate to millisecond precision!)

Comment: I'm aware timestamps aren't an ideal primary key but they're actually part of a two-part key which includes the foreign key to the 'owner' of the record and are only created in response to user interaction. I need to record and display the creation date and time of the entity (which can't be changed). Interested to hear if you have a specific reason that I should be adding an additional column for a purist primary key purpose (in place of the timestamp)?

Comment: Just tidying up my questions... Your approaches are sound they just didn't quite fit what I needed. Regardless they'll hopefully help others with this issue.